# bash and telnet to test an email

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command, telnet

I'm trying to find out whether an email address is valid.

I've accomplished this by usign telnet, see below

```
$ telnet mail.example.com 25
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to mail.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com Mon, 14 Jan 2013 19:01:44 +0000
helo email.com
250 mail.example.com Hello email.com [0.0.0.0]
mail from:blake@email.com
250 OK
rcpt to:gfdgsdfhgsfd@example.com
550 Unknown user
```

with this 550 request i know that the address is not valid on the mail server... if it was valid i would get a response like the below:

```
250 2.1.5 OK
```

How would I automate this in a shell script? so far I have the below

```
#!/bin/bash
host=`dig mx +short $1 | cut -d ' ' -f2 | head -1`
telnet $host 25
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth noting that most large mail providers, including GMail, Hotmail and Yahoo Mail disallow this technique to prevent spammers from harvesting live accounts.

Comment: @that other guy
I've actually tried with gmail and it *does* work, just in a different format ......
   `code` mail from: <name@email.com>
    rcpt to: <testing@gmail.com>`code`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
[[ $4 ]] || {
    printf "Usage\n\t$0 <domain> <email> <from_email> <rcpt_email>\n"
    exit 1
}
{
    sleep 1
    echo "helo $2"
    sleep 0.5
    echo "mail from:<$3>"
    sleep 0.5
    echo "rcpt to:<$4>"
    echo
} | telnet $1 25 |
    grep -q "Unknown user" &&
    echo "Invalid email" ||
    echo "Valid email"
```

Usage :

```
./script.sh domain email from_email rcpt_email
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always enter your commands into a plain text file, line after line, just as if you typed them on the command line.  Then you can use something like

```
cat commands.txt | telnet mail.example.com 25 | grep -i '550 Unknown User'
```

Since you will probably need to consider this text file as template, (I am assuming you will probably want to parameterize the e-mail address) you may need to insert a call to awk to take the output of 'cat commands.txt' and insert your e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

## variables to change

```
BODY="open realy smtp test"
SMTP-SRV="server_ip"
SMTP-PORT="25"
RCPT="name@domain"
SRC="name@domain"
```

## then run in bash

```
/bin/nc ${SMTP-SRV} ${SMTP-PORT} << EOL
ehlo example_domain.com
mail from:${SRC}
RCPT to:${RCPT}
data
From:${SRC}
To:${RCPT}
subject: Telnet test
${BODY}
.
quit
EOL
```